# Stiff ODE solvers for non-stiff problems

Tags: solver, ode, numerical-integration

In many sources ([example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/types-of-solvers.html)) it is stated that stiff ODE solvers are designed to solve stiff problems and non-stiff ODE solvers are designed to solve the non-stiff ones.

My question is: what is the cost of using a stiff ODE solver for a non-stiff problem? 
Is it only performance issue or are there any examples when it is easy (as compared to using non-stiff ODE solvers) to get incorrect results with wrongly chosen parameters (I know the answer here may be subjective).

Comment: As this question is not about programming, I would consider it off-topic here. It is however a good fit for [scicomp.se].